# This code works in console, but not in a migration. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can happily execute this line in a Rails 4.2.0 console:

```
State.update_all(country_id: Country.where(iso_abbr: 'US').first_or_create(name: 'United States').id)
```

These two models hav a bit of magic: both of them have a method like this:

```
def iso_abbr=(value)
    super((value||'').upcase)
end
```

I have no trouble running this in a console. Works as expected (the new country record is created if absent, and on every state currently in database is set as the country). But the case is not that when running that in a migration.

The error I get tells me that there's no `super` for that method:

> super: no superclass method `iso_abbr=' for #<Country:0x005612cf9f8ca0>/.../country.rb:8:in`iso_abbr='

What am I missing? Why is it working on console but not on migrations?

state.rb file:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :iso_abbr, :name, :country, :postal_code_usage
  validates_inclusion_of :postal_code_usage, in: %w(country doesnt_use requires), if: :postal_code_usage
  validates_uniqueness_of :iso_abbr, scope: :country_id
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :counties, dependent: :destroy

  def iso_abbr=(value)
    super((value || '').upcase)
  end

  def is_fl?
    @is_fl ||= iso_abbr == "FL"
  end

  def uses_postal_code?
    case postal_code_usage.to_sym
      when :country
        country.uses_postal_code?
      when :doesnt_use
        false
      when :requires
        true
    end
  end
end
```

country.rb file:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :iso_abbr, :name, :postal_code_usage
  validates_inclusion_of :postal_code_usage, in: %w(doesnt_use requires), if: :postal_code_usage
  validates_uniqueness_of :iso_abbr
  has_many :states, dependent: :destroy

  def iso_abbr=(value)
    super((value || '').upcase)
  end

  def uses_postal_code?
    case postal_code_usage.to_sym
      when :doesnt_use
        false
      when :requires
        true
    end
  end
end
```

Migration code:

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :countries do |table|
      table.timestamps
      table.string :iso_abbr, unique: true
      table.string :name, null: false, limit: 100
      table.string :postal_code_usage, null: false, limit: 10, default: :requires
    end

    change_table :states do |table|
      table.string :postal_code_usage, null: false, limit: 10, default: :country
    end

    # I tried here to put Country.reset_column_information but did not help.

    reversible do |direction|
      direction.up do
        # THIS LINE EXPLODES.
        State.update_all(country_id: Country.where(iso_abbr: 'US').first_or_create(name: 'United States').id)
      end
      direction.down do
        State.update_all(country_id: nil)
      end
    end

    reversible do |direction|
      direction.up do
        # Disallowing null in the column ...
        change_column :states, :country_id, :integer, null: false
      end
      direction.down do
        # Disallowing null in the column ...
        change_column :states, :country_id, :integer, null: true
      end
    end

    # Add the unique index to both fields ...
    add_index :states, [:iso_abbr, :country_id], unique: true

    create_table :addresses do |table|
      table.timestamps
      # Location Type: :regular for regular addresses, :no_number if given street + property name,
      #                :no_street if given just property name.
      table.string :location_type, null: false, limit: 10
      # Address Type: :individual for regular houses, :shared if in building or complex
      table.string :residence_type, null: false, limit: 10
      # Actual address fields here (they must be unfilled or null according to `location_type`)
      table.references :state, null: false
      # IMnshO the reference should be done against :county instead of :state
      table.string :city, null: false, limit: 100
      table.string :street, null: true, limit: 70
      table.string :name, null: true, limit: 70
      table.string :number, null: true, limit: 16
      # Postal code will be required, or not, according to what the state tells.
      table.string :postal_code, null: true, limit: 16
      # Extra data will be required exactly when `residence_type`==:shared and nil otherwise
      table.string :extra, null: true, limit: 100
    end
    # A state in use cannot be deleted (so we avoid breaking the whole data).
    add_foreign_key :addresses, :states, column: :state_id

    change_table :clients do |table|
      table.references :address, null: true, default: nil
    end
    add_foreign_key :clients, :addresses, column: :address_id
  end
end
```

**Edit**: I found the reason but not a satisfying workaround. **The same migration is creating, previously, the countries table in database**. This means that `iso_abbr=` cannot be attended by `super` (i.e. call in `ActiveRecord::Base`) since the class had the former column information, not including the just-created columns.

I tried this code after creating the table:

```
Country.reset_column_information
```

Because I thought it would reload the column information including the new columns, but I still get the error.

How can I reload the data so I can get a `super` handling of the field by default?

Comment: i dnt know whats super there ))) but you can simple do like this: `before_save { self.iso_abbr = (value || '').upcase }`

Comment: What does your migration look like? If you're adding the `iso_abbr` in the same file, then you have to do `Country.reset_column_information` so the model knows about the new column.

Comment: @sjagr I tried what you said but did not work

Comment: @7urkm3n perhaps I will try that solution...

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Ah, I think it means the model is trying to find the super class on autoload, which happens before your migration even occurs.

Comment: Hierarchy: `Country < ActiveRecord::Base`. Why did not work reloading the class with your method?

Comment: @LuisMasuelli forget to change, where `value`supposed to be `iso_abbr ` or depends what params passing there. as i understand yr trying to save iso_abbr with data or empty string.

Comment: The key part of this is the migration, which isn't shown here.  Please post the migration code.

Comment: I will edit and post it...

Comment: Added the migration code

Comment: @MichaelGaskill ...............

Comment: It's likely that `create_table :countries` is clobbering your `iso_abbr=` when it rewrites the class methods when defining the field accessors.  Since `iso_abbr` is a field, there's a conflict that will get resolved by overwriting.  I suggest either splitting the migration into multiple migrations (each with a specific structural purpose) or the ugly way: using `reset_column_information` and immediately re-opening the `Country` model class and overriding the `iso_abbr=` with the same code used in the actual class.

Comment: I don't know why `reset_column_information` gave you a problem. It helped me with a similar problem. Maybe you didn't save the file? Maybe they fixed that method in Rails 5.0.6?